# iOS web service sync -ascyn

Tags: ios, service, web, synchronization

From the web service delay the data how can o do that the same process.When data came from the web service I want the write to the db .But data a little delaying .How can ı solve this problem.

Comment: English is not my first language, but I can't figure out what concrete problem you're asking for a solution for. Could you clarify what you really need help solving and what the problem is?

Comment: when ı get the data from web service .Service be late.and I want to sync .How can ı do that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question completely.  It looks there are two parts.

1. You can use multithreading for your web service call so it won't block your current UI.  Grand Central Dispatch can be used to manage such process for you.  Here is a tutorial on [GCD](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial).
2. If you are using NSURLConnection, there are delegates that you can implement to wait for those callbacks.  Here is one [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) from Apple.